# Pattern Matching BlankSequence

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider the definition:

```
Clear[fun]
fun[a_ + b_] := fun[a] + fun[b];
fun[a+b+c]
(*fun[a] + fun[b] + fun[c]*)
```

This works as expected. However, if we use a `BlankSequence` on "b":

```
Clear[fun]
fun[a_ + b__] := fun[a] + fun[b];
fun[a + b + c]
(*fun[a] + fun[b, c]*)
```

it seems that  `BlankSequence` eliminates the `Plus` in "b+c" and replaces it with `Sequence`.
Has anybody a good explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a+b+c == Plus[a,b,c]`

So `fun[a_ + b__]`  == `fun[Plus[a_,  b__]]`

when input `a + b + c`,which equals `Plus[a,b,c]` , mma match `b` with `b,c`

```
a + b + c /. a_ + b__ :> {a, {b}}
```

> {a, {b, c}}

Comment: Hi, here a follow up question: Can you explain why the "b" in the following expression gets lost?: Clear[fu]
fu[a_ + b__] := fu[a] + fu[(Print[FullForm@Hold@b]; b)];
fu[a + b + c]

Comment: @DanielHuber I tried these 2 code: `a + b + c /. a_ + b__ :> {{a}, {None; b}}` and `a + b + c /. a_ + b__ :> {{a}, {b}}` , find something interesting. I am not able to explain it.

Comment: HI, the same happens with any symbol you like. E.g.a + b + c /. a_ + b__ :> {{a}, {gaga; b}} There are some mysteries with BlankSequence that I do not understand